# Is it possible to find exclusive matches (in or group statement) with a backreference?

Tags: regex, backreference

I was reading up on backreferences [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) but this is all about matching a whole capturing group. Let's say I have following strings:

```
"This is a test to find the dog."
"This is a dog that I will test."
"This test is made to test."
"This is a test to test a dog."
```

1 and 2 should match, 3 and 4 shouldn't.

I want to know if it's possible to match the string only if `test` and `dog` are found exclusively from eachother, so if `test` is encountered first, only `dog` will give a match and vice versa. Something like:

```
(dog|test).*\1
```

Except that the backreference should match either `dog` or `test` depending on what was found first.

**Sidenote:**
I know I could do it with `(dog.*test|test.*dog)` but I want to know if it's possible with backreferences (or another way).

Comment: What about "This test is made to test dog.": Valid or invalid? In other words, should it contain both words, or should not not contain any word twice, or both?

Comment: @tobias_k Let's say that's valid to not make it too complicated, but if it were possible to really exclusively find them it would be nice though.

Comment: @sln Can you give an example of how I could use it to conditionally test it? Does that mean I can say `if( \1 == dog) then test else dog`? Something like that (but translated to regex of course)?

Comment: @sln [That works](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3a(dog)%7ctest).*%3f(%3f(1)test%7cdog)&i=This+is+a+test+to+find+the+dog.%0d%0aThis+is+a+dog+that+I+will+test.%0d%0aThis+test+is+made+to+test.), I guess my problem is pretty much solved then, if you want post it as an answer. I wonder if tobias' suggestion is possible though, to really find exclusive matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test a backref with a conditional, otherwise you can only match a backreference.
A backreference is constant to a capture buffer, it can't be altered, only conditionally tested.

Example  `(?:(dog)|test).*?(?(1)test|dog)`

**Update**

Not captured word twice

`((dog)|test)(?:(?!\1).)*?(?(2)test|dog)`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Going to test if they can be totally exclusive too

Comment: Added exclusive regex too. Be aware, it can be unlimited exclusive forms.

Comment: "This is a test to test a dog." does give a match too. But that wasn't my initial question so thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Btw, the second regex will match highlighted part only _This is a test to `test a dog`_

Answer (score 1):

Use negative look ahead to prevent matching when either term appears twice:

```
^(?!.*?(test|dog).*?\1).*(test|dog).*
```

This *doesn't* match "This is a test to test a dog."  (as expected).

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/AqI8uSifvn).

Comment: This doesn't work. It doesn't match `This dog is a test` but it does match `This test is a test` so it does the opposite

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean then by "test and dog are found exclusively from eachother"? Or better: Of the 3 examples in your question, which should match (and why)?

Comment: `dog` and `test` should only be in the string once

Comment: @AlexanderDerck OK, the regex now matches as you wanted

Comment: Very nice, didn't think this would be possible. So it's a negative lookahead for `test` or `dog` twice but why is the `.*(test|dog).*` needed afterwards?

Comment: The negative look ahead *prevents* unwanted matches, but you still need to *match* `test|dog`. The leading `.*` is needed because to work correctly the negative lookahead needs to be anchored to start (using `^`), so the match starts at start of line (not at the target word). I put a `.*` at the end so the match is the whole line containing `test|dog` (without which it would match from start to the target word, which seems wrong).

Comment: Just re-reading your question, is it that *both* test and dog need to be in the line, but which ever is found first must appear exactly once? So "foo test dog dog" should match, but "foo test dog test" should not?

Comment: yes, both `test` *and* `dog` should be exactly once in the string, not more, not less. With this little edit it works: `^(?!.*?(test|dog).*?\1).*(test.*|dog.*){2}` so it doesn't match a single `dog` or `test` anymore

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time! :) (and sorry for confusing title/question, it's hard to explain)